# Module is not available when running Elixir exq workers

Tags: elixir, sidekiq, exq

I have built an async job processing app using Elixir [exq](https://github.com/akira/exq). The documentation says that I can run the application using both the terminal (with `iex -S mix`) or as a standalone application (with `mix exq.run`). When I run on the terminal, everything works fine, but when I run the standalone app, I get this message when the jobs are fetched:

```
16:52:55.028 [info]  Elixir.MyWorker[128f902c-dd22-4706-95a2-89dc974b95d6] start

16:52:55.045 [error] Process #PID<0.196.0> raised an exception
** (UndefinedFunctionError) function MyWorker.perform/1 is undefined (module MyWorker is not available)
    MyWorker.perform("arg1")
    (exq 0.14.0) lib/exq/worker/server.ex:186: anonymous fn/4 in Exq.Worker.Server.dispatch_work/3

16:52:55.052 [info]  Queueing job 128f902c-dd22-4706-95a2-89dc974b95d6 to retry in 24.0 seconds
```

What am I doing wrong?

Here is my `lib/my_worker.ex` file:

```
defmodule MyWorker do
  def perform(arg) do
    IO.puts("teste: " <> arg)
  end
end
```

and my `mix.exs`

```
defmodule WorkersSandbox.MixProject do
  use Mix.Project

  def project do
    [
      app: :workers_sandbox,
      version: "0.1.0",
      elixir: "~> 1.10",
      start_permanent: Mix.env() == :prod,
      deps: deps()
    ]
  end

  # Run "mix help compile.app" to learn about applications.
  def application do
    [
      applications: [:exq_ui, :exq],
      extra_applications: [:logger]
    ]
  end

  # Run "mix help deps" to learn about dependencies.
  defp deps do
    [
      {:exq, "~> 0.14.0"},
      {:jason, "~> 1.0"},
      {:exq_ui, "~> 0.11.0"},
      {:plug_cowboy, "~> 2.0"}
    ]
  end
end
```

and my `config/config.exs`:

```
import Config

config :exq,
  start_on_application: true,
  name: Exq,
  host: "127.0.0.1",
  port: 6379,
  # password: "",
  namespace: "exq",
  queues: [{"default", 10_000}, {"fila2", 10_000}],
  poll_timeout: 50,
  scheduler_poll_timeout: 200,
  scheduler_enable: true,
  max_retries: 25,
  mode: :default,
  shutdown_timeout: 5000
```

Comment: Have you tried `mix do app.start, exq.run` as https://github.com/akira/exq#standalone-exq suggests?

Comment: Yes, it worked. These instructions were updated after I opened this issue: https://github.com/akira/exq/issues/432

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in [this issue](https://github.com/akira/exq/issues/432),

you should start the workers with this command:

`mix do app.start, exq.run`

or just

`mix run --no-halt`

should work in these cases. The exq.run mix task just starts the exq application, not the main app. The documentation was updated to be clear about this.